# Government versus Agreement

Tags: syntax, theoretical-linguistics, dependency-grammar, agreement

Taking English as an example, as I understand things, the case of a pronominal Subject is **governed** by the verb—it must be nominative:

- She loves elephants.
- *Her loves elephants. (ungrammatical)

Conversely, the verb **agrees** with the grammatical number of the Subject. So if the Subject is plural, the verb must be in a plural form (i.e. 1st, 2nd, 3rd person plural form):

- We love elephants.
- *We loves elephants. (ungrammatical)

These at first seem like quite similar things: each component must be compatible with the other. So what is the difference between government and agreement. Why do we not say that the Subject *governs* the verb, or that the Subject *agrees with* the verb?

In other words:

- **What are the syntactic and semantic properties/elements of government and agreement**?

Answers with regard to any particular language are appreciated.

---

<sup><sup>**I reserve the right to ask questions (I think) I  know the answer to.**</sup></sup>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140018/discussion-between-araucaria-him-and-lambie).

Comment: Interesting question. I find that I use _govern(ment)_ to refer to selectional restrictions (_English sense verbs can govern all four complement types_), while _agree(ment)_ refers to constituent marking (_German noun phrases agree in gender, number, and case_). Government (by predicates or heads) seems universal, but agreement is a morphological phenomenon and requires paradigms.

Comment: So, did you have a chance to read Melcuk on government vs agreement? All my comments were deleted, for some reason. I might write a brief summary, when I get more free time.

Comment: @AlexB. Shame. Maybe if you stick them in the chat they won't get deleted. (Or post them both there and here).

Comment: I'm posting the links to Melcuk now, going to add more later https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110199864.1.31/html and https://www.jbe-platform.com/content/journals/10.1075/li.17.2.04mel

Comment: "the case of a pronominal Subject is governed by the verb": Isn't the verb form based on the subject, nominal or pronominal?? I'd say: the subject governs the verb.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing is that government means that one controls the other, a sort of "If (*) then (*)" relationship, whereas with agreement both arguments can be changed to produce a grammatical sentence. Using your examples, in the sentence "She loves elephants," one cannot change both "she" and "loves" to get some related sentence wherein the word "her" is used, meaning the verb **governs** the subject. On the other hand, in the sentence "She loves elephants," it would be perfectly grammatical and related to say "She loves the elephant." Disregarding the rules of definite article use (I'm not opening that can of worms), this sentence changed the object while retaining the verb, therefore meaning the verb **agrees** with the object.

Comment: The verb doesn’t agree with the object. It agrees with the subject, which remains unchanged. If you change the subject, the verb changes too: “*We loves elephants” is ungrammatical.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That's a much better and less long-winded explanation XD.